# xCode Same app different WS automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, build

I have 3 environments:
- UAT
- STAGE
- PRODUCTION
on each of these there are web service with different pointments.
Before publishing the app testers made tests on any environment (so i have to change ws pointments, rebuild, resend ipa, etc and most important problem is newer version overwrites the old one - having the same bundle id)
I really like having the same app on my device 3 times (one for environment) together and do it **automatically** (something like Build Configuration).
Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I usually add a settings bundle where the user can select what endpoint to use. Just make sure you are not adding the bundle when you build it for App Store. I usually use the preprocessor to check if a certain symbol is defined and add the bundle only then. For instance `#ifdef DEBUG` might work.

Comment: Thanks. But in this case I'd have only one app on my device. I'd like to have three equals apps but with differents pointments.